# Как вызвать исключение DivideByZeroException?

Tags: c#

Необходимо вызвать исключение DivideByZeroException для последующей его обработки.

Код ниже рассчитывает зарплату на основе стажа работы.

```
public virtual int GetSalary()
{
     Salary = (50000 + (1000 * Experience));
     return Salary;
}
```

Как вызвать исключение не искусственным способом?

Comment: `int a = 0; int b = 999644 / a;` но в показанном методе это исключение никогда не возникнет, потому что там нет операции целочисленного деления.

Comment: чтобы получить исключение о делении на 0, нужно как минимум поделить на 0

Comment: @Grundy я понимаю, что нужно делить на 0. Как мне сделать так, чтобы при увеличении опыта работы увеличивалась зарплата и при этом было деление на переменную `Experience`?

Comment: сначала нужно определиться из чего у тебя состоит зарплата и как на нее должен влиять Experience

Comment: @Grundy базовая зарплата 50000. За каждый год работы к зарплате добавляется 1000. Experience - целое число. Если `Experience = 0`, то `Salary = 50000` и при этом должно вызываться исключение DivideByZeroException.

Comment: @wesbi, судя по описанию - не должно вызываться исключение:) Так как в этом случае значение в Salary не должно присваиваться

Comment: @Grundy так я и спрашиваю как это можно реализовать

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132312/discussion-between-grundy-and-wesbi).